# How to mount encrypted windows partition in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, encryption, grub2, dual-boot

i have asked this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/186519/how-to-mount-safeboot-encrypted-windows-partiton-in-ubuntu) and I want more replies please

---

how do I mount a SafeBoot encrypted Windows partition on Ubuntu (10.04)?

I had a harddisk with safeboot encrypted windows partition. I resized the partition and then installed ubuntu on the free space. Now my windows doesn't load

I have tried mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

tried changing fstab tried changing grub.cfg

I also installed ntfs config tool but it doesn't detect the windows partition

but sudo fdisk -l show me the windows partition on /dev/sda1 with ntfs

---

If I can't mount the windows partition now, can you tell me how do I dual boot? When I switch on my laptop, it directly boots into Ubuntu without any grub menu. How do I fix this issue to show a grub menu and dual boot into both windows & ubuntu?

Comment: Here is results.txt ( http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5NpsUPt0 ) file the boot info script (from http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/)

Comment: I'm confused with your post - you seem to be skirting around two ideas between what the title says, the tags say, and the body of the question. Are you trying to mount a SafeBoot Windows Partition or trying to setup Grub to dual boot Windows/Ubuntu? Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

Like the responses in SU mentioned the encrypted partition onto which windows was installed is not really a ntfs partition - it contains data in a format only safeboot can understand. Now to have dual boot in such a system would have needed you to resize the partition before Safeboot encryption was setup.

There is one way to reach the situation you want (dual boot with Windows on a safeboot encrypted partition and ubuntu on another), if the following prerequisites are met:

1. You are willing to backup all the data and reinstall ubuntu
2. You are willing to backup all the data and reinstall windows and windows apps
3. You are willing to setup the encryption again.
4. You have some kind of windows or safeboot rescue cd (see [this](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/20000/PD20487/en_US/SafeBoot_and_Windows_Rescue_CDs.pdf))

Even with all these, the method I can think of has some caveats. Read along. These are the steps:

1. backup all data in ubuntu partition. To make restoration easier you could note the list of packages already installed by running the following command and backing up the resulting `selections.txt` file

   ```
    sudo aptitude --get-selections > ~/selections.txt
   ```
2. Boot into ubuntu livecd / liveusb and delete the ubuntu partition.
3. From within the same live user session, resize the ntfs partition to its original size (the size it was before you started to install ubuntu).
4. reboot with the safeboot+windows resuce cd and repair the system.
   Ideally this should detect a damaged boot record and should restore the possibility to boot back into windows within the encrypted partition.

## Caution

I am totally not aware of safeboot and never used it and don't know if there is a rescue cd or if it can do step 4. The step 4 is only a helpful suggestion based on a few minutes of googling. Take support of your IT or of mcaffee if possible.

With the above you should have your system back at the same state *before* you started installing ubuntu.

Now you need to resize your ntfs partition - this is not possible by `fdisk`, `gparted` or the ubuntu installer if the partition is encrypted. So, if it is possible, turn off encryption temporarily and decrypt the entire partition in place temporarily, then resize it and turn back encryption on. Again I am a total illiterate novice w.r.t safeboot trying to help with an abstract conceptual suggestion the practical application of which you need to figure out. If switching back to non-encrypted mode temporarily is not possible (due to tool constraints or lack of space) then u need to back up all data and settings and application information and re-install windows and apps again after re-partitioning the disk (because, repartitioning will mean a reformat of entire disk in this case).

If you get this far, putting back ubuntu on the remaining space available should be trivial. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the DualBoot Question:

Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to display the hidden menu during boot (<kbd>ESC</kbd> in GRUB legacy).

(by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)